# Xamarin Android - Google Play service Authentication and Azure mobile service backend

Tags: xamarin, azure-mobile-services, google-authentication

I am using the new google SDK for authentication on android.

Here is the code that I use to get the authentication token

```
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
                .RequestEmail()
                .RequestId()
                .RequestIdToken(serverClientID)                    
                .RequestServerAuthCode(serverClientID)
                .Build();


        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .AddApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)                    
                .Build();
```

Then under the activity result, I get the id token:

```
// Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.SignInAccount;

var idToken = acct.IdToken;
var authorizationCode = acct.ServerAuthCode
```

Everything works fine up to this step. 
Then I try to call the azure mobile client to authenticate. Here is the code. I pass in the id token and authorization code.

```
var zumoPayload = new JObject();
zumoPayload["id_token"] = idToken;
zumoPayload["authorization_code"] = authorizationCode;

user = await this.client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, zumoPayload);
```

This step fails. I get some unknown error. It seems the id token that I am passing to azure mobile service is not working.

Just to let you know that I have already setup the google project and also enabled google authentication under azure portal. The google authentication works fine when I use server flow. But this client flow is not working for some reasons. Any idea what I am doing wrong?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow), you need to pass the `access_token` returned from google, then use the following code for authenticating with your mobile apps:

```html
var zumoPayload = new JObject();
zumoPayload["access_token"] = "{access_token}";

user = await this.client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, zumoPayload);
```

**Note:** Since you are using the client authentication flow, you independently contact your identity provider, you need to retrieve the `access_token`, then pass it to your azure mobile apps backend, at this time your mobile backend would send request to the related rest api by using the access_token to get the logged user profile, then it would issue a JWT token named the `authenticationToken` to your mobile client.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to simulate sending request against azure mobile app for client authentication flow as follows:

```
POST https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google
Body {"access_token":"{your-access-token}"}
```

But I retrieved the following error:

> 400 'id_token' field is required.

I did test the client-authentication flow for MSA，Facebook,Google,etc. But there seems that something changed for the client authentication flow via Google account. I changed the payload and just sent the `id_token`, then it could work as follows:

[image]

In general, you just need to remove `zumoPayload["authorization_code"] = authorizationCode;`, then your logging should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how to get the access token from the google provider? I tried the following code bu that GetToken method seems to be deprecated. <br />    var token = GoogleAuthUtil.GetToken(context, acct.Account.Name, GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_SCOPE);

Comment: I did some test, you could refer to the details for solving your issue.

Comment: Bruce, thanks very much for your help. It is working now! One more thing that I had to do - when I tried to call "LoginAsync" under OnActivityResult, it seems I was running into a thread dead lock. To overcome that issue, I had to call it like this:  user = Task.Run(async () => { return await client.LoginAsync(authenticationProvider, zumoPayload); }).Result;

Comment: @MS you dont need to have accesstoken from google, you can use IdToken directly. it confuses are because facebook sdk returns access token. see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

i just want to add my 2 cents here. I was able to implement on Android using Facebook SDK and Google SDK natively and then register those into Azure Mobile Services. trick here is Facebook SDK provides you actual access token but Google SDK doesnt give you that instead, you are getting IdToken from google. You need to request is as below

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
                                                         .RequestEmail()
                                                          .RequestIdToken("yourClientCode")
                                                          .RequestServerAuthCode("yourClientCode")
                                                         .Build();
```

Then pass that IdToken to the Mobile Azure Services as below

```
var zumoPayload = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
                    if(provider== MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook)
                    zumoPayload.Add("access_token", accessToken);

                    if (provider == MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google)
                        zumoPayload.Add("id_token", accessToken);

                    var result = await App.Client.LoginAsync(provider, zumoPayload);
```